# Exception when creating a Stream from csv file

Tags: c#, csv, embedded-resource

I have a csv file in the same project with a Build Action of "Embedded Resource".  When I try to create a stream using this file I get the following error:

```
system.io.stream.null.readtimeout threw an exception of type system.invalidoperationexception
```

When I let it run I catch an exception that says:

```
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: stream
```

I am not sure what is causing this?  Is it possible that it's not picking up my file for some reason and therefore nothing gets passed into the stream?

```
internal static void InsertPropertyDefinitions()
        {
            DataTable csvData = null;

            string[] columnNames = null;
            int rowCount = 0;
            string[] streamDataValues = null;
            try {
                using (Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
                    "My csv file path"))
                {
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        String streamRowData = streamReader.ReadLine().Trim();
                        if (streamRowData.Length > 0)
                        {
                            streamDataValues = streamRowData.Split(',');
                            if (rowCount == 0)
                            {
                                rowCount = 1;
                                columnNames = streamRowData.Split(',');
                                csvData = new DataTable();

                                foreach (string csvColumn in columnNames)
                                {
                                    DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(csvColumn.ToUpper(), typeof(string));

                                    dataColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

                                    csvData.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DataRow dataRow = csvData.NewRow();

                                for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    dataRow[columnNames[i]] = streamDataValues[i] == null ? string.Empty : streamDataValues[i].ToString();
                                }

                                csvData.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    streamReader.Close();
                    streamReader.Dispose();

                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in csvData.Rows)
                    {
                        string rowValues = string.Empty;

                        foreach (string csvColumn in columnNames)
                        {
                            rowValues += csvColumn + "=" + dataRow[csvColumn].ToString() + ";  ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You got a read timeout.  I would try to figure out why the timeout occurred.

Comment: I'm thinking that is coming from the last exception which is telling me that my stream is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by **resourceName** :

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.csv";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    ...
}
```

The resource name is not necessarily equal to the name of the file. You can check using *Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();*

Usually VS add namespace to resource name. Then **MyList.csv -> NS.MyList.csv**

To get names

```
 var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 var lst = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
 Console.WriteLine("Files");
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lst));
```

Comment: stream is still null

Comment: Please, add ouput for Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

Comment: assembly.GetManifestResourceNames error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'GetManifestResourceNames' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: but aren't we setting a variable with a lower case "a"ssembly?  If I caps "A"ssembly then we are no longer using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() right?

Comment: MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.csv is how I have my file path.  I noticed you are outputting to a write line in the edited code.  I am inserting into a DataTable.  also you have (string.Join(", ", a).  Where is the variable 'a' coming from?

Comment: No problem so question how would this line appear with lst included     using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))

Comment: because programmatically I cannot do using (Stream stream = lst(resourceName))

Comment: Did you can get the list correctly?   You just need the correct resource name into original code

Comment: So I just dug a little deeper and realized there was a "." where their shouldn't have been one in my file path.  Sorry about the confusion.  Big thanks for your effort and assistance though.

Comment: Great! always is a " . " or " , " or " ; " . Keep your eyes fresh